# R Apply function to list and create new dataframe

Tags: r, plyr, rbind

I am wanting to retrieve data from several webpages that is in the same place on all the pages and put it all in one data frame.

I have the following code attempt:

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)

**##the urls**
raceyears<-list(url2013,url2012,url2011)

**##function that is not producing what I want**
raceyearfunction<-function(x){
page<-readLines(x)
stats<-page[10:19]
y<-read.table(textConnection(stats))
run<-data.frame(y$V1,y$V2)
colnames(run)<-c("Country","Participants")
rbind.fill(run)
}

data<-llply(raceyears,raceyearfunction)
```

This places all the data in multiple columns (two columns for each webpage) but I am wanting all the data in two columns (Participants, Country) one data frame not many columns in one data frame.

I haven't found a question quite like this already on the site but am open to follow a link.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of your data? That will be very helpful for SO users to help you.

Comment: This is the output and essentially three of these are produced, 10 rows 2 columns
> head(data)
[[1]]
   Country Participants
1      USA       552761
2      JPN       238470
3      GER       115855
4      FRA       100640
5      ENG        77384
6      ITA        58677
7      ESP        54421
8      POL        36533
9      RSA        35870
10     CAN        30196

Comment: Do you think you can provide the urls? That would help all SO users to see what is happening.

Comment: This is the url pertaining to the 2014 data:
url2014<-"http://www.arrs.net/MaraList/ML_Stats2014.htm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use rbindlist outside of raceyearfunction. Let it `return(run)` without `rbind.fill(run)`.

You can use ldply instead, then it will return binded data.frame already.

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)

raceyears <- list(url2013,url2012,url2011)

raceyearfunction<-function(x)
{
    page <- readLines(x)
    stats <- page[10:19]
    y <- read.table(textConnection(stats))
    run <- data.frame(y$V1,y$V2)
    colnames(run) <- c("Country","Participants")
    return(run)
}
data<-ldply(raceyears, raceyearfunction)
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by including a complete set of code rather than instructions for how to change the OP's current code.